# How can I regain write permission on my Time Machine sparsebundle?

Tags: macos, time-machine, permission, time-capsule, sparsebundle

For my backup I use an encrypted virtual disk on a sparsebundle file that is stored in an external hard drive attached on a router via USB. This file is accessed via samba but for one reason I decided to use the HD directly attached to my mac. So I changed permission to access the file, because previously they were assigned to the user created on the router to access via smb, but I haven't only chmod the directory. I chown it for my mac user.
Now when I try to mount the .sparsebundle it mount but Time Machine says it's in a readonly state and I'm not even able to actually read it.

I tried to search the web for some days but I wasn't able to find the solution.
I tried to force fsck_hfs but below is the result.

Anyone can help me? I specify that the physical volume on the external drive is an EXT4 filesystem because the router runs on Linux. Maybe it add information to find the solution.

```
sudo hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck /Volumes/Data/Dati/Time\ Machine.sparsebundle/
/dev/disk3              Apple_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk3s1            Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk3s3            Apple_HFS                       


sudo fsck_hfs -rc -fd /dev/disk3s3
    ** /dev/rdisk3s3
       Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.50.6).
       Invalid content in journal
    ** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
       The volume name is Time Machine
    ** Checking extents overflow file.
       Unused node is not erased (node = 2784)
    ** Checking catalog file.
    ** Rebuilding catalog B-tree.
       Disk full error
    ** The volume Time Machine could not be repaired.
       Invalid content in journal
    (4, 0)
```

**EDIT:**
Actually it could be also a filesystem problem, not (only) a permission one

```
hdiutil attach /Volumes/Data/Dati/Time\ Machine.sparsebundle/
hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems
```

For testing purpose I attached again the HDD to the router and reenabled the smb share.
Here is some screenshot of my setup.

The smb share mounted on macos, with the sparsebundle that always mount in readonly
[image: img1]

The HDD mounted on the homemade NAS (/dev/sda3)
[image: img2]

The configuration of the Samba share (access -> read and write, even if we cannot read it from the screenshot)
[image]

The permission settings on the directory mounted on the router
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Executed fsck directly from the smb share. I cannot understand the difference but the output is much more verbose:

```
mbp:~ asdasd$ sudo hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck /Volumes/HDD-3TB/Time\ Machine.sparsebundle/
/dev/disk2              Apple_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk2s1            Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk2s3            Apple_HFS                       
mbp:~ asdasd$ sudo fsck_hfs -dyf /dev/disk2s3
journal_replay(/dev/disk2s3) returned 0
** /dev/rdisk2s3
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=32768 cacheSize=1048576K.
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.50.6).
   Invalid content in journal
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
   The volume name is Time Machine
** Checking extents overflow file.
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2784)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2785)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2786)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2787)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2788)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2789)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2790)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2791)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2792)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2793)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2794)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2795)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2796)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2797)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2798)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2799)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2800)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2801)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2802)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2803)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2804)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2805)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2806)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2807)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2808)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2809)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2810)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2811)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2812)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2813)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2814)
   Unused node is not erased (node = 2815)
** Checking catalog file.
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xC4663BAF)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x5C275BF7)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-86)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (125)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x7A07)
   Invalid record count
(4, 138355)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x4503418D)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x2A4FB6A0)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (13)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (204)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0xA115)
   Invalid record count
(4, 138349)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xA89C3ED0)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x01F29D8B)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (58)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (244)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x4C27)
   Invalid record count
(4, 117907)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xBD984CDE)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x605E0605)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (82)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (255)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x545E)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15346)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x10253D99)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xE20E4C52)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (5)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (62)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x46A0)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15350)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x89065B23)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xEC5EA33C)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (109)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (138)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x22B2)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15351)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xCB62D10A)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xE4D99839)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (38)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (178)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0xA660)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15354)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x96DA8F15)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x0425140D)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (55)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (193)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0xB64A)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15356)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x1BFF8923)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x322A6002)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-86)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (50)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x2556)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15361)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x55587FAC)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xBFFCD97E)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (53)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (31)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x3D2E)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15363)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xF0AB994A)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xD761E74A)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (52)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (241)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x83C7)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15359)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x8265BB41)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xDBAB6D74)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-117)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (89)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0xB62B)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15366)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xA075EE7A)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xA396FB09)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (4)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (249)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0xE600)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15367)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x60AE6546)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x2DC43D0E)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (25)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (163)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x1620)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15372)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x14D20EF4)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x6DA1EB27)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-43)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (13)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x3B82)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15376)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x4502411B)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x27F70985)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-71)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (133)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x391E)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15380)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xD5E9CF80)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x8D0C5384)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (95)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (81)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x68C2)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15384)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xCD183754)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x4162C8FC)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (24)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (46)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x6AAA)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15388)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x30398884)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x5D6E1DEF)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (94)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (35)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0xB4BA)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15390)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x9ED1D2C2)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x927DFDD5)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-17)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (229)
hfs_swap_BTNode: offset #0 invalid  (0x9FF7) (blockSize 0x2000 numRecords 1843)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 15392)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x7293EA34)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x1079EF12)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (35)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (7)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x6341)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15399)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xC34E551E)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xB58FFB11)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (52)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (154)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x7A42)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15406)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x62012680)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x25D211FD)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (89)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (87)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x6038)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15414)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xE8995EC5)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xACFEC80F)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (115)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (240)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x6CED)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15430)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x4E0F412C)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xEB45452D)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (21)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (253)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x8B26)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15439)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x16E2F4F5)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xB2D9EC11)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (4)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (90)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x59F3)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15443)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xFE2CA3C7)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x8E2D4CAA)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-11)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (238)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x8B13)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15453)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xB1B3FE24)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x06F47091)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (126)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (171)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x54F7)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15457)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x7B8EDD20)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x86BB009C)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-30)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (82)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x9C0B)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15459)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x3385DB18)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xD6BA8FAD)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-119)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (192)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x5DE7)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15451)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xF61BE3A7)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xB9C758D4)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-8)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (132)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x9329)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15466)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xCE4305BC)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xE513F9D8)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-103)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (227)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x5868)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15470)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xB6E6C582)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xBF967F87)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (16)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (95)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0xD4BD)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15474)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x43C7A9AD)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x55670FA5)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-61)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (43)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x6EFA)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15476)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xF930D5AA)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x92E89158)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-66)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (97)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x3969)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15478)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x0356D5D6)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x8C032195)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (41)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (110)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x8BC2)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15504)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x719EAB8D)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x866A3F4B)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (60)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (52)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0x4268)
   Invalid record count
(4, 15510)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0xE9849E68)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0x4444F22C)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (120)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (202)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0xCA19)
   Invalid record count
(4, 118664)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45169)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45169)
Node 45169's back link is 0x0; expected 0x7758
    disk offset = 0xcd8fd000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45169)
Node 45169's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb074
    disk offset = 0xcd8fd000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45169)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45169)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45189)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45189)
Node 45189's back link is 0x0; expected 0xb082
    disk offset = 0xcd925000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45189)
Node 45189's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb081
    disk offset = 0xcd925000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45189)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45189)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45185)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45185)
Node 45185's back link is 0x0; expected 0xb085
    disk offset = 0xcd91d000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45185)
Node 45185's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb089
    disk offset = 0xcd91d000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45185)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45185)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45200)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45200)
Node 45200's back link is 0x0; expected 0xb08e
    disk offset = 0xcd93b000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45200)
Node 45200's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb092
    disk offset = 0xcd93b000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45200)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45200)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45206)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45206)
Node 45206's back link is 0x0; expected 0xb09a
    disk offset = 0xcd947000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45206)
Node 45206's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb09c
    disk offset = 0xcd947000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45206)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45206)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45212)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45212)
Node 45212's back link is 0x0; expected 0xb096
    disk offset = 0xcd953000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45212)
Node 45212's forward link is 0x0; expected 0x18d4b
    disk offset = 0xcd953000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45212)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45212)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45217)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45217)
Node 45217's back link is 0x0; expected 0xb09f
    disk offset = 0xcd95d000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45217)
Node 45217's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb0a5
    disk offset = 0xcd95d000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45217)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45217)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45232)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45232)
Node 45232's back link is 0x0; expected 0xb0b5
    disk offset = 0xcd97b000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45232)
Node 45232's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb0b7
    disk offset = 0xcd97b000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45232)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45232)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 101709)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 101709)
Node 101709's back link is 0x0; expected 0xb0bc
    disk offset = 0xe92b5000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 101709)
Node 101709's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb0bd
    disk offset = 0xe92b5000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 101709)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 101709)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45245)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45245)
Node 45245's back link is 0x0; expected 0x18d4d
    disk offset = 0xcd995000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45245)
Node 45245's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb0c1
    disk offset = 0xcd995000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45245)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45245)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 132677)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 132677)
Node 132677's back link is 0x0; expected 0x20646
    disk offset = 0xf84a5000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 132677)
Node 132677's forward link is 0x0; expected 0x7760
    disk offset = 0xf84a5000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 132677)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 132677)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 30560)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 30560)
Node 30560's back link is 0x0; expected 0x20645
    disk offset = 0xc66db000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 30560)
Node 30560's forward link is 0x0; expected 0x20655
    disk offset = 0xc66db000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 30560)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 30560)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45251)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45251)
Node 45251's back link is 0x0; expected 0x18d50
    disk offset = 0xcd9a1000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45251)
Node 45251's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb0d0
    disk offset = 0xcd9a1000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45251)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45251)
   Invalid node structure
(4, 45265)
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45265)
Node 45265's back link is 0x0; expected 0x20683
    disk offset = 0xcd9bd000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid sibling link
(4, 45265)
Node 45265's forward link is 0x0; expected 0xb0d5
    disk offset = 0xcd9bd000, size = 0x2000
   Invalid node height
(4, 45265)
Index key doesn't match first node key
   Invalid index key
(4, 45265)
** The volume Time Machine could not be verified completely.
    volume check failed with error 7 
    volume type is pure HFS+ 
    primary MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    primary VHB is at block 2 0x02 
    alternate VHB is at block 1952453214 0x7460125e 
    sector size = 512 0x200 
    VolumeObject flags = 0x07 
    total sectors for volume = 1952453216 0x74601260 
    total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00 
    CheckForClean - could not get VHB/MDB at block 1952453214 
    CheckHFS returned -1317, fsmodified = 0
```

Comment: If `fsck_hfs` complains about not being able to repair a volume it's probably not related to an access permission issues (I'm not saying this might not be an issue *as well*, but it shouldn't cause the errors you see).

Comment: But I'm not sure I understand your setup correctly, and the changes you've made. Originally the sparse bundle was stored on an EXT4 filesystem mounted on the rounter, and accesses via SMB? How did you get this mounted directly on your Mac?

Comment: Hi, yes the sparsebudle was and is stored on a EXT4 volume. The HDD was attached to a DD-WRT router with USB cable and accessed via smb from my Mac. Then I mount the sparsebundle found on the share and did Time Machine stuff. 
I did this to manage disk usage and chose how many space dedicate to TM and how many to other data using a single partition.
It's something like a homemade NAS setup

Comment: Now I'm trying to access the sparsebundle directly because I'm going to change my laptop and I don't want to access it via the network because it's slow for the first backup

Comment: If you attach the disk to the router again, can you mount the sparsebundle?

Comment: Yes, it mount, but always in read only mode. I'm gonna edit the main post with some screenshots

Comment: Please don't post images of text. For more information, see [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).